# How Euler showed that number :$2305843008139952128$ is perfect without using computer calculation?

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, perfect-numbers

This number : $2305843008139952128$ is perfect as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2305843+008139952128++is++a+perfect+number) and it was proved that is a perfect number by Euler without using computer , then

> > **My question here is:**
> >     How Euler showed that number :$2305843008139952128$ is perfect without using computer calculation ?.

Comment: Ever heard of Mersenne primes?

Comment: but that is not a prime may you meant mersann formula for perfect number which is 2^(n-1)(2^n-1)

Comment: I never said it is. Yes, I mean that formula. Now, $2^{31}-1=2\,147\,483\,647$, and that is not awfully big. You can check it for primality by hand, given enough time.

Comment: by your idea it is easy to check large mersann prime for the exponent is prime if i understand you well

Comment: http://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/MerDiv.html

Comment: @Chappers throw that up as an answer

Comment: Great! We have (that is, Euler had) to check the primes below 46341, and only those of them equal to 1 or 63 mod 248. There are only 84 of them. BTW, Lucas-Lehmer test was not known yet.

Comment: Here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime it is mentioned that Euler actually proved $2^{31}-1$ to be prime via trial division (probably with the mentioned restriction) and he probably already knew the form of every even perfect number.

Comment: Of course he knew. _Euclid_ knew that, for God's sake!

Comment: What do you meant by God's sake ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Euler was the one to prove that all even perfect numbers are of the form
$$2^{n-1} ( 2^n - 1 )$$
This is known as the [Euclid-Euler Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem), and says that we just have to prove that $2^n-1$ is prime. Your number is
$$2^{30} ( 2^{31} - 1 )$$
Which Euler got by just plugging integer $n$ into the equation above. Now, we have that
$$2^{31}-1=2\,147\,483\,647$$
is small enough to be checked for primality by hand. Euler did this by utilizing modular properties of the [Mersenne Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), as @Chappers and others note in the comments above. In essence Euler lowered the number of cases to check considerably by noting that if $2^{31}-1$ was composite with divisor $p$ then either $p \equiv 1 \pmod {248}$ or $p \equiv 63 \pmod {248}$

Answer (score 2):

Since the number given is $2^{30}(2^{31}-1)$, all that needs to be done is show that $2^{31}{-}1$ is prime. Euler knew that factors of this number must be of the form $k(2\cdot31)+1$, and also must be $8n\pm1$. This gives $84$ primes to check for division up to $\sqrt(2^{31}-1)$

See [Modular restrictions on Mersenne divisors](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/MerDiv.html) from the Prime Pages.